# Magento and Media Temple, playing nicely

Tags: optimization, mediatemple, media, magento

I am trying to get the page load time as low as possible in my Magento store. I am using a Media Temple (dv) Extreme, which has 2GB of RAM.

I have had APC setup along with Fooman Speedster plugin for caching the CSS/IMAGES etc.

The page load time is around 5-7 seconds at the moment but it seems much slower, I'm not sure if Safaris inspector is accurate or not.

The store is nowhere near completed, I have imported around 3900 products but not all of them will be in the final store catalog. When the database is empty the store runs quite well.

I modified the mySQL with the following edits:

```
[mysqld]
query-cache-type = 1
query-cache-size = 96M
join_buffer_size = 512K
tmp_table_size = 128MB
max_heap_table_size = 32M
thread_cache_size = 8
table_cache = 512
key_buffer = 512M
max_allowed_packet = 64M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
max_connections = 400
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
max_connections = 400
wait_timeout = 300
```

The address is:

http://hillcrestanimalhospital . co . uk/store/

So, with the exception of APC, Fooman Speedster and the mySQL edits are there any other options for getting this faster *without* renting a completely separate server for the database?

Would a RAM upgrade make any difference at all?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe first try to pinpoint the bottle-neck. you can use generic method - run parallel looped requests to your shop and see if your server cpu gets saturated? if so - by which process - apache/php or mysql? i guess at this it's not ram that holds you back.

Comment: Hi. Inappreciate the answer but I'm not sure how to

Comment: do what you suggest. Do you know of any tutorials on finding bottlenecks etc.?

Comment: start using eg ab - apache benchmark and running top at the same time. google for lamp optimization, see also here: http://serverfault.com/questions/11739/lamp-server-performance-tips