# Where to start? Server profiling tools

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LAMP Server Performance Tips](https://serverfault.com/questions/11739/lamp-server-performance-tips)

So I have a website, users upload images, people view images etc. Simple enough. Lots of writes and reads everywhere. Its built in MySQL and PHP on Apache.

We have one dedicated server. Right now we are getting hammered with unexpected press and users and our CPU cycle is out of control, slowing down the entire site.

Off hand I am guessing its either the saving of the image to the disk, or the Mysql queries.

What tools can I use to educate myself on what is happening and pinpoint the problem? How can I find out what is happening in detail in this time of crisis?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: The operating system is Cent OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try New Relic. It is a service that can analysis which PHP functions and MySQL queries are taking time and will automatically analyse those queries to see why it is slow. It costs money but you could use their trial to debug your problem.

Comment: Awesome, looks promising I will check it out now!

Comment: Turned out to be exactly what I needed. Thanks again