# Optimize server for faster processing of requests

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, wordpress, debian-squeeze, mysql5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LAMP Server Performance Tips](https://serverfault.com/questions/11739/lamp-server-performance-tips)

I am running a web directory using WordPress which has a lot of categories, and I mean a lot. Around 26,000 to be precise. And it takes WordPress forever to finish processing certain requests. The homepage takes around 120 seconds to finish processing and then the data is sent over. I recently moved this to a different host which has 2 GB RAM. I am using BitNami LAMPStack.

I am wondering what it is that effects the time required to process a request? Apache, MySQL, PHP or all? I am hoping I can bring the amount of time it takes down significantly and I would appreciate if someone could maybe point me to the right direction? I have tried playing with apache configuration and mysql file(s).

And apache is using prefork and mod_php

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/a/11741/113375

Comment: one way is to not use LAMP, use nginx+php-fpm instead like we use, we've described how we do it at http://www.logicwreck.com/index.php/2012/07/02/nginx-php-fpm-mysql-for-serving-wordpress-sites/

Comment: Nothing server-side is going to help a badly built site. Rebuild your site.

Answer (score 0):

Use a faster web server like [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) and enable Opcode and WordPress [object caching using APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).  The quality of your code also has a lot to do with it.

[Reduce the number of queries](http://yoast.com/wordpress-performance-optimization/), cache results using the [enter link description here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache)WordPress API, [cache static html versions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) of your pages using Varnish or a load balancer.